# Bash Program fails to start MarkLogic instance - Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted

Tags: bash, docker, marklogic

I am new in dockers and bash scripting. I have to build a single container which will install MarkLogic application and deploy some files in the installed MarkLogic server.
I have written one docker file to execute a wrapper script. The wrapper script will execute 2 scripts (in bash), script1 to install and start the MarkLogic instance and script2 to deploy some file in the new installed MarkLogic server.

The script1 has installed the MarkLogic server but unable to start the instance. And gives me the below error -

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start etc-init.d-MarkLogic.mount

Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
```

Below is the script1 which is failing to start the MarkLogic instance-

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get any CentOS updates then clear the Docker cache
#install yum by rpm 
#yum -y update && yum clean all
cp MarkLogic-10.0-9.4.x86_64.rpm MarkLogic.rpm
# Install MarkLogic dependencies
yum -y install glibc.i686 gdb.x86_64 redhat-lsb.x86_64 && yum clean all

# Install the initscripts package so MarkLogic starts ok
yum -y install initscripts && yum clean all

# Set the Path
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/MarkLogic/mlcmd/bin"


# Install MarkLogic then delete the .RPM file if the install succeeded
yum -y install MarkLogic.rpm && rm MarkLogic.rpm

service /etc/init.d/MarkLogic start
```

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/825027/14483

Comment: I have tried this, and it gives this error:  
 docker run -d -it --privileged mlinstalldeploytde:latest /etc/init.d/MarkLogic 
2d786b1de80db9f9691a9eda38f1153e246bf1e46b0efed5acb4f3bd19e6c421
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/etc/init.d/MarkLogic": stat /etc/init.d/MarkLogic: no such file or directory: unknown

Comment: Broadly, commands like `service` and init scripts like `/etc/init.d` or `/etc/rc.d` just don't work in Docker.  A Docker container runs only one process, not a full init system, and typically you'd set the image's `CMD` to run whatever service as a foreground process.

Answer (score 0):

There is an official docker image for MarkLogic here https://hub.docker.com/r/marklogicdb/marklogic-db